# Add Raster Points Into Another Plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I need to make a raster plot like the one shown in the figure. All the points must be saved so I can make the next figure, which is seen as the "Gaussian shaped bell" The problem is, it is the Gaussian shape there must determine the density of points in the raster plot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\xCellOne}{3}
\newcommand{\yCellOne}{10}
\newcommand{\xTimeLineS}{5}
\newcommand{\xTimeLineF}{9} 
\newcommand{\yTimeLineS}{8}
\newcommand{\yTimeLineF}{11}    


%\path[use as bounding box,draw,black] (10,12) rectangle (0,0);

\draw[] node at (\xCellOne,\yCellOne) (cellOne) {Cell 1};
\draw[] node[below = of cellOne ] at (\xCellOne,\yCellOne) {Cell 2};

\foreach \y [count=\c] in {-0.5,-1,...,-2.5}
{   \node[right] at (\xTimeLineF,\y+0.1+\yTimeLineF) {\scriptsize Subject 
\c};
\foreach \x in {1,...,70}
{   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\drawbool}{rand-0.4 > 0 ? 1 : 0}
    \ifthenelse{\drawbool=1}
    {   \fill (\x/20+\xTimeLineS,\y+\yTimeLineF) rectangle 
 (\x/20+\xTimeLineS+0.02,\y+0.1+\yTimeLineF);}
    {}
}
}

\draw[-stealth] (\xTimeLineS,\yTimeLineF) -- (\xTimeLineF,\yTimeLineF);
\node[right] at (\xTimeLineF,\yTimeLineF+0.2) {t in ms};
%\foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \v using int(20*\x)] in 
{\xTimeLineS,...,\xTimeLineF}
%{   \draw (\x,-0.05) -- (\x,0.05) node[above] {\v};
%}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should remove the indent of the image link to make it visible.

Comment: Your image and the output of your code look very different. What are you trying to do? What's the problem you face in drawing the picture? What is the problem you face in calculating something?